# Get-Mailbox equivalent in EWS api

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365

I am looking for method to get the list of all the mailboxes through ews api.

Is there any method call,Get-Mailbox cmd in powershell, that can get me the list of all the mailboxes in an exchange server/ office 365 in EWS API?

Answer (score 2):

No. EWS is used to access mailbox data, not get lists of mailboxes. Get-Mailbox is the way to do it, and you can invoke this programmatically if needed.

Answer (score 1):

[ExchangeService.GetSearchableMailboxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.getsearchablemailboxes(v=exchg.80).aspx) is what you need, specify the the filter as an empty string, then you get all the mail boxes.

Comment: Note this gives all the mailboxes in the organisation and requires the eDiscovery permissions, (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53478951/350188) rather than just the mailboxes the current user can access.