# The caller has not assigned any of the RBAC roles requested in the management role header

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, microsoft-exchange

I am trying to access the Exchange mail boxes via Exhange webservice. A user 'abc' has right to access the Exchange mailbox. I can create folder,read and send email from the mailbox of user 'abc'.

But When I try to search for another mailbox 'def' using the method 'GetSearchableMailboxes', I get the following error.

> The caller has not assigned any of the RBAC roles requested in the management role header.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

EWS eDiscovery Operations require the calling user to have a Discovery Management RBAC. See this link for more information: [Assign eDiscovery permissions in Exchange Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298059(v=exchg.160).aspx)

Comment: @mzh did this answer your question? if so, please mark it as the answer, to help others who come across this question in the future